# How to map to the same function with a pattern that ends with or with "/" with http.HandleFunc

Tags: go

I'm using golang *net/http* function `http.HandleFunc` to associate a URL pattern to a function.

I would like to know if there's something better than doing

```
http.HandleFunc("/foo", fooFunc)
http.HandleFunc("/foo/", fooFunc)
http.HandleFunc("/bar", barFunc)
http.HandleFunc("/bar/", barFunc)
```

to match fooFunc to both *"/foo"* and *"/foo/"* endpoints and so for *bar*.

As a bonus, how could I limit the foo func to only for instance `GET` requests.

(Thank you!)

Comment: A better solution: just register one path with trailing slash, and you get the other one for "free". Quoting from `http.ServeMux`: _"If a subtree has been registered and a request is received naming the subtree root without its trailing slash, ServeMux redirects that request to the subtree root (adding the trailing slash). "_

Comment: @icza awesome, Thank You. For reference: the documentation can be found here: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution: just register one path with trailing slash, and you get the other one for "free".

Quoting from [`http.ServeMux`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux):

> If a subtree has been registered and a request is received naming the subtree root without its trailing slash, ServeMux redirects that request to the subtree root (adding the trailing slash).