# Golang handlefunc

Tags: http, go, routes

So I have this weird issue where some routes will work and others won't. I will first show you my main function and then give examples of what the problem is.

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", home)
    http.HandleFunc("/project", project)
    http.HandleFunc("/about", about)
    http.HandleFunc("/contact", contact)

    http.Handle("/resources/", http.StripPrefix("/resources", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./assets"))))

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ListendAndServe doesn't work : ", err)
    }
}
```

For example, the route "/contact/" does not work, when I run this code and go to localhost/contact it will send me to the homepage. However when I change the route in the Handlefunc to "/contactos" and then go to localhost/contactos it does work.

Another example, "/project" works now, but when I change it to "/projects" it does not.

Comment: Please note that if you register `/project/` (note the trailing slash), then both `/project/` and `/project` will work (with or without trailing slash). If you register `/project` (without a trailing slash), then only `/project` will work, `/project/` will be matched by the root handler `/`.

Comment: Okay great it works, thanks XD

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you register `/project/` (note the trailing slash), then both `/project/` and `/project` will work (with or without trailing slash). If you register `/project` (without a trailing slash), then only `/project` will work, `/project/` will be matched by the root handler `/`.

Quoting from [`http.ServeMux`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeMux):

> **If a subtree has been registered and a request is received naming the subtree root without its trailing slash, ServeMux redirects that request to the subtree root (adding the trailing slash).** This behavior can be overridden with a separate registration for the path without the trailing slash. For example, registering "/images/" causes ServeMux to redirect a request for "/images" to "/images/", unless "/images" has been registered separately.

See related questions:

[How to map to the same function with a pattern that ends with or with "/" with http.HandleFunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60159221/how-to-map-to-the-same-function-with-a-pattern-that-ends-with-or-with-with-h/60184270#60184270)

Comment: This solved my problem!  Not sure why there are not more upvotes.